# JQuery Validator unhighlight on Bootstrap Accordion

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

On a standard bootstrap accordion I've got some standard bootstrap inputs that I need to validate by the panel. So if there is an error the panel heading text changes colour. I also need this to change back when all the fields inside that panel are valid.

The JS I'm using is:

```
var validator = $(this).data('validator');
    if (typeof (validator) != "undefined") {
        validator.settings.ignore = [];
        validator.settings.highlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            var formgroup = $(element).on().closest(".form-group");
            if (typeof (formgroup) !== "undefined") {
                formgroup.addClass("has-error");
                if (!formgroup.hasClass("conditional")) {
                    if (formgroup.is(":hidden")) {
                        formgroup.show();
                    }
                }
            }
            var accordionHead = $(element).on().closest(".panel");
            if (typeof (accordionHead) !== "undefined") {
                accordionHead.addClass("acc-error");
            }
        };
        validator.settings.unhighlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).on().closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
        }
        validator.settings.unhighlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
           $(element).on().closest(".panel").removeClass("acc-error");
        }
    }
```

Yet all this does is change the colour on leaving one invalid field and then on entering another it changes it back to the error colour again. Is there anyway I can get round this? I've already tried copying the validation from highlight into unhighlight, but this gave me the same problem.

Comment: Your code looks very unusual.  [Refer to these to see more typical code when using these two libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate+twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code...

```
var formgroup = $(element).on().closest(".form-group");
```

---

- [jQuery `.on()` is used for attaching event handlers to elements](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  As per documentation, it cannot be left empty, nor is it used as part of selecting anything.  `$(element).closest(".form-group")` would be sufficient.
- You've tried to define the `unhighlight` setting twice.  The second instance will over-ride the first.  Combine them into one.

---

You can get rid of the `.on()` and combine everything you'd need into one instance of `unhighlight`...

```
validator.settings.unhighlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
   $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
   $(element).closest(".panel").removeClass("acc-error");
}
```

Clean up the rest of your code accordingly.

---

```
if (typeof (validator) != "undefined") { ...
```

BTW - When using jQuery, you never need to check for the existence of an object or element before selecting it.  If the selected item does not exist, jQuery will simply ignore it without any errors or issues.